# ReactJS - How to use DatePicker from Material UI with Firestore? Timestamp to Date format

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, material-ui

The date is recording OK in database, but when I show then the DatePicker does not reconigze the date from the database because with comes like timestamp (seconds and nanoseconds).

```
  <DatePicker
    margin="normal"
    label="Data do pedido"
    fullWidth
    value={
     form.datapedido   
    }
    onChange={handleChangeData}
      variant="filled"
      style={{ marginTop: 0 }}
  />
```

If I change the value of DatePicker to make Timestamp to Date then I cannot save the date because the code will try to change a Date to Date.

If I leave this way then I can save the date but when I load the date from firestore I get "Invalid Date" from DatePicker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore [timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp)includes a `toDate` method you can use to convert your date into a javascript Date object,
assuming your component is expecting a Date object.

So, assuming `form.datapedido` is a `Timestamp` object:

```
<DatePicker
    margin="normal"
    label="Data do pedido"
    fullWidth
    value={
     form.datapedido.toDate()
    }
    onChange={handleChangeData}
      variant="filled"
      style={{ marginTop: 0 }}
  />
```

You will find a challenge probably when you want to update your picker (after loading the initial value).

This can be useful:

```
const formatDate = (date) => isNil(date.seconds)
   ? date // Already a javascript date object
   : date.toDate()

<DatePicker
    margin="normal"
    label="Data do pedido"
    fullWidth
    value={
     formatDate(form.datapedido)
    }
    onChange={handleChangeData}
      variant="filled"
      style={{ marginTop: 0 }}
  />
```

This might do the trick or give you a starting point, I'm not familiar with the `DatePicker` component

Comment: Great answer! Thank you! This is exactly what I need.

Comment: glad to help brother

Comment: if you are not using `lodash` you won't find `isNil` function. Change `isNil(date.seconds)` to `!date.seconds` and it will work.